# Running a .bat script in IICS informatica using Command task

Tags: informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud, iics, informatica-data-integration-hub

I am using IICS with A WINDOWS environment. I would like to know if there is any method to run the .bat script using the COMMAND TASK ?
I could see steps to run the .bat file in the linux env. but not in windows

Comment: There should be no issue, just put the command with the path. But... We are taking about the batch file located on IICS Secure Agent, that is running on Windows, right? We're not talking about a batch file from your local machine? Just making sure :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not run .bat file in linux.
So you either have to modify the script to shell or you can install "wine" package in Linux to use it.  You have to do this in IICS secure agent server.

Option 1 - modify the bat script in shell script.
Option 2 - Install wine in Linux. You can download wine package from https://www.winehq.org/ and install in linux.

Once installed, change  user's bashrc file (~/.bashrc). Add

```
export WINEPREFIX=$INSTALL_HOME/.wine/
export WINEHOME=$INSTALL_HOME/.wine/
# for 32-bit
export WINEARCH=win32
# for 64-bit
export WINEARCH=win64
```

Type below script to run your bat_script file in Informatica cmd task.

```
wine cmd.exe /c bat_script.bat
```